# Common pattern when variable is used before being assigned

Tags: typescript

I have a module

```
import pino, { Logger } from 'pino';

let logger: Logger;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    const dest = pino.extreme();
    logger = pino(dest);
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    // @ts-ignore
    logger = pino({ prettyPrint: { colorize: true } });
}

...

export default logger;
// ^^^ [ts] Variable 'logger' is used before being assigned. [2454]
```

Here is no any situation when logger is undefined, but even if it will be undefined it is suted for me

How to resolve the TypeScript error at the end:

> Variable 'logger' is used before being assigned. [2454]

I've rewritten my code but the error still here

```
import pino, { Logger } from 'pino';

let logger: Logger;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    const dest = pino.extreme();
    logger = pino(dest);
} else 

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    // @ts-ignore
    logger = pino({ prettyPrint: { colorize: true } });
} else

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === undefined) {
    throw new Error('Logger must be initialized! Set up process.env.NODE_ENV');
}

if (logger) { // <-- Variable 'logger' is used before being assigned. [2454]
   // configuring process
}

export default logger;
```

Even in another way

```
import pino, { Logger } from 'pino';

let logger: Logger;

function configureProcess(theLogger: Logger) {
  // setup process with theLogger
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    const dest = pino.extreme();
    logger = pino(dest);
    configureProcess(logger); // <-- code duplication
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    // @ts-ignore
    logger = pino({ prettyPrint: { colorize: true } });
    configureProcess(logger); // <-- code duplication
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === undefined) {
    throw new Error('Logger must be initialized! Set up process.env.NODE_ENV');
}

export default logger;
// ^^^ [ts] Variable 'logger' is used before being assigned. [2454]
```

I feel like a fighter against TypeScrit instead of developer - so many dances to solve a problem which is not a problem in reality (

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> but even if it will be undefined it is suted for me

I would suggest that having `logger` be `undefined` is not a good idea (more below), but based on your statement above:

Make that explicit, to the compiler and to maintainers of the code:

```
switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
    case 'production':
        const dest = pino.extreme(); // logs to stdout with no args
        logger = pino(dest);
        break;
    case 'development':
        // @ts-ignore
        logger = pino({ prettyPrint: { colorize: true } });
        break;
    default:
        logger = undefined; // That's fine
        break;
}
```

(Doesn't have to be `switch`, `if`/`else if`/`else` works too.)

Also note that you'll need to allow `logger` to have the value `undefined`, [as VinceOPS points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53415844/157247):

```
let logger: Logger | undefined;
```

---

**Note**: This means that anything *using* `logger` has to allow for it having the value `undefined`. I wouldn't do that if I were you. Instead:

1. If you only need to support the two configurations you list, either:

   1. Only check for one of them and then assume the other:

      ```
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
          case 'development':
              // @ts-ignore
              logger = pino({ prettyPrint: { colorize: true } });
      } else { // production
              const dest = pino.extreme(); // logs to stdout with no args
              logger = pino(dest);
      }
      ```

      or
   2. Throw an error in the third branch:

      ```
      switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
          case 'production':
              const dest = pino.extreme(); // logs to stdout with no args
              logger = pino(dest);
              break;
          case 'development':
              // @ts-ignore
              logger = pino({ prettyPrint: { colorize: true } });
              break;
          default:
              throw new Error("process.env.NODE_ENV must be either 'production' or 'development' to use this module");
      }
      ```
2. If you want to support all three possibilities (`production`, `development`, or neither), initialize `logger` to a valid `Logger` in the third branch as well, perhaps a "do nothing" logger.

That would be much better than letting `logger` be `undefined`.

Comment: after checking conditions here is going some code for configuring proccess - so it's not sutable using switch in my case

Comment: @Vadim - I don't see why not, but in any case, the fundamental point is the same: Assign `logger` a value on every path. Worst case, assign it `undefined` where you declare it, but better to structure things so that you get warned when your conditions have a path through them you haven't handled.

Comment: What should I do when I don't want to have logger is undefined and my code above is never gives a chance a logger to be undefined?

Comment: @Vadim - Throw an error if that's not a valid configuration for this module. Or if it is, always assign it a `Logger` (again: possibly one that doesn't do anything).

Comment: Again, this seems like a bad concession to make, every module which imports the logger has to now do an `undefined` check before using it.  There's no need to make it possibly undefined, see my answer for a simpler solution without the `undefined` caveat

Comment: @Alex - See the last paragraph, where I raise that very concern. (Edit: Though I just realized I should fold part of a comment I made above into it.)

Comment: if logger is not declared as possible undefined - default section of switch raises error

Comment: @Vadim - Right. As I said above, if supporting something other than those two branches isn't something you want to do in your code, **throw an error** in the default branch.

Comment: @Alex - It *was* the last paragraph [at the time](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53415766/2), now I've beefed up that entire section. I shouldn't have taken *"...but even if it will be undefined it is suted for me..."* at face value.

Comment: @Vadim - I've folded my comments above into the answer now.

Answer (score 11):

Or simpler, assuming that:

> but even if it will be undefined it is suted for me

Replace

```
let logger: Logger;
```

With

```
let logger: Logger | undefined;
```

If `logger` **can be** undefined, then annotate it as **possibly undefined**. Then `tsc` won't complain anymore.

Comment: That solves a different problem than the one the OP asked about (but it's their **next** problem :-) ).

Comment: True. But adding an `else` in the execution paths (or doing a `switch/case/default`) won't give any additional hints to `tsc`, thus, I assume the KISS principle applies here!

Comment: Well, as I said, it's their **next** problem. But again doesn't address *this* problem, unless you mean doing that will get rid of the error quoted without any other changes...? (Since `undefined` is the default if there's no initializer...)

Comment: @VinceOPS - Yes it will.  `tsc` can follow exhaustive branching logic, he can simply use an if/else instead of two if statements and the compiler would be happy to recognize that `logger` must have been set.

Comment: @Alex switch with `case / case / default` is somewhat equivalent to `if / else if / else`, if the `else` is only setting to `undefined`, then this is somewhat equivalent to `if / else if` with a default assignment. So, nope, no additional hint for `tsc` in **this specific case**.
@T.J.Crowder You're right, my bad, forgot about this S.O "guideline" :-).

Comment: I have to disagree with this answer, he now has to unnecessarily deal with it being possibly `undefined` for every other module which imports it.  That's a pretty horrible concession to make for your logger, which is going to be used many many times.

Comment: You're making assumptions about the OP's codebase/business logic, here; my answer concerns `tsc` & type inference only, and would not change even if `logger` was called `foo` and of type `Bar`. "Other modules" importing it would be informed of its possible _undefinedness_, and this is where TypeScript becomes really powerful. I do not see the link/issue here. Anyway, I hope one of the proposed solutions will suit the OP! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to make it also be assignable to `undefined`, if your branching logic is exhaustive, then the compiler will understand that `logger` must be assigned.

I'm assuming that you only ever want to support two logging modes, `production` or else always `development`, so just make it an if/else and the compiler will be happy

```js
import pino, { Logger } from 'pino';

let logger: Logger;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  const dest = pino.extreme(); // logs to stdout with no args
  logger = pino(dest);
} else {
  logger = pino({ prettyPrint: { colorize: true } });
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === undefined) {
  throw new Error('Logger must be initialized! Set up process.env.NODE_ENV');
}

export default logger;
```

Comment: thanks for the sample.
But there is a 3 case - when process.env.NODE_ENV is undefined and where to put a rest common code?

Comment: @Vadim, you can make it an if/else if/else similarly.  Are you ever going to leave `logger` as `undefined`?  I assume that you *always* want a logger to be defined, no matter how many variations you have. If you do intend to leave it `undefined` in some circumstance, then the other answers are correct, your type should reflect that with `| undefined`

Comment: I need not logger to be undefined. where should I put my code after logger initialization? Repeat it in every case? If I put it after `if/else` - I have the error !

Comment: `development` environment ignored? Why `logger` should necessarily be defined btw?

Comment: I've chnge the code in question - have a look please

Comment: @Vadin, I've updated my answer to reflect what you've described.  In this manner, you're guaranteeing that `logger` is defined and the compiler will be happy.  The key difference here is that we're using a simple if/else to ensure it's assigned in all cases.  This is the part that makes `tsc` compile fine.  You can then do other sanity checks, such as the `NODE_ENV === undefined` check and bail out then, without affecting the compilers decision about the type safety

Comment: Thanks. I've caught it but where should I place my process setting code where I am using logger variable? Have a look at the editet code in my question.

Comment: Why would someone downvote this answer? I'd handle the `if`/`else` differently, but it's nowhere near a downvote situation. Geez people.

Answer (score -2):

Here is the final working code

```
import pino, { Logger } from 'pino';

let logger: Logger;

switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
    case 'development':
        // @ts-ignore
        logger = pino({ prettyPrint: { colorize: true } });
        break;
    case 'production':
        const dest = pino.extreme(); // logs to stdout with no args
        logger = pino(dest);
        break;
    default:
        throw new Error('Logger must be initialized! Set up process.env.NODE_ENV');
}

// here is the code fo setting up the process with the logger
setInterval(() => logger && logger.flush(), 10000).unref();

export default logger;
```

Comment: ts does not understand `if/else` correctly - only `switch/case`