# How to handle unassigned variables in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

The following Typescript code results in a compile error `ts(2454): Variable "timeout" is used before it has been assigned` in the catch statement.

```js
let timeout: NodeJS.Timeout
try {
    prepareConnection(() => {
        timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('timeout while opening connection');
        }, 10000);
        openConnection();
    });
} catch (err) {
    if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout); //<-- Error ts(2454)
    console.error('error while opening connection');
}
```

**What would be a good way to approach to satisfy the compiler?**

see also question [Common pattern when variable is used before being assigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53415708/common-pattern-when-variable-is-used-before-being-assigned)

Comment: get setTimeout outside of the try block :)

Comment: @Icepickle this would indeed solve the problem, but my code is a little bit more complex. `setTimeout` is in reality called within another callback. See above!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best solution here is to use a [Definite Assignment Assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions) (availible since typescript 2.7).

> The definite assignment assertion is a feature that allows a ! to be placed after instance property and variable declarations to relay to TypeScript that a variable is indeed assigned for all intents and purposes, even if TypeScript’s analyses cannot detect so.

```js
let timeout!: NodeJS.Timeout //add a exclamation mark "!"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a perfectly valid typescript assumption that something could have gone wrong inside the try block before assigning the `setTimeout` result to the timeout variable.

So the only safe way to go about it would be to move the `setTimeout` out of the `try` block, so at the time of the declaration (what can really go wrong with a setTimeout, I think you don't really care about that, but rather about any errors that happen during the `openConnection` statement

**Update based on OP edit**

As you mentioned that it's a bit more complicated, assigning it with any valid value at the time of declaration would also do, ie:

```
let timeout: NodeJS.Timeout = null;
```

Comment: Setting timeout to `null` or `undefined` results in an error `ts(2322): Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'NodeJS.Timeout'`.