# Unable to overwrite a variable value in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, variable-assignment

I am making a loop function for a 2D array. It looks like:

```ts
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {
    let workid: number
    let starting_time: number
    let ending_time: number

    if (j === 0) {
      continue
    } else if (j === 1) {
      workid = array[i][j]
      starting_time = j
      ending_time = j
    } else {
      if (array[i][j] === workid) {
        ending_time = j
      } else {
        testingShift.push({
          empId: i,
          workAreaId: workid,
          startTime: starting_time,
          endTime: ending_time
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to achieve if last [i][j] `workid` is the same as the previous one then `ending_time = j`, if not then I push the values in the array object.

The problem is in my last else condition:

```ts
} else {
  if (array[i][j] === workid) {
    ending_time = j
  } else {
    testingShift.push({
      empId: i,
      workAreaId: workid,
      startTime: starting_time,
      endTime: ending_time
    })
  }
}
```

it is giving the error 'variable is being used before assigned'. I understand that it is not assigned at the beginning but after the first loop `else if (j === 1)` all the values will be set.

I do not understand what I am doing wrong.

[Working Code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAKgggSgcQKJQFwQHYFcC2AjEAJwG0BdCAXgmIAYAaCARgYCYGBmUgbgCgeB6fhAQgMRAIZgAlhgDmEMAAsQCkAGdpciCwC0AEQjjChcQE8eAMywYAxtID2GVRpmyYxswAoAlBADePBBBEDaOGhCE6ljAYOjiGKZklJggAO4Q7iamnow03ryBwRb2hBCeoJBSyTRcEFUAPBFRMQB0oHJKtVIA1N2+AcGDTWrRYMRS5FRkvIMAvnyDxaXl4HXVXRCNuV29-QtDQRWYuASlVLCIKMSeALKSii0WwPYlt-ctJhgAJvY4PhAAKmg8GQUDaolkSm83lIhQOSzKRwAVusICjGgBWWpI3b+fYHQZSCxlFEUKh5PEEqnDUbjUjEJGTNbdJgzalBWYQEDANQqAbsoaREYxOkMpnYfBENns+ZwobzKkS07JC6g653JSPZ6vDUPT4-P6+IGqlDgjqKaGwqkIlaQUkQLFozYQACc2NxATlVKJJMo5L2AsFzTGEzFySqLMY0upnO5vMpgeCQtpocZySVUq9BNlVIVBIzZ2Blyg6veTxehDemv1v3+xpBpvakItMKzQRtyOSbqdW3Y7r6CfZPs8pP9g8TyZFqaZEdZbflXJ5fPnVMnIfpaaoBejufx8rleaCkTAWEITjXPFlfB4MjARAs4hsKjvLjkAEkMHfCA+n+OQDgAAc3y+AB+dACzoOVUhKABrdwQHEYCwOOSVCEgwYNCMMAoCkHAQGQiC5VEL4cLwgiTiIS8+FCDBwhfTQ3A8UwAHk8CREA7HQejXA-L8fxAJIplha8aPCIwshEMQTDvL5km4uRMi8bxqLCexQDaexZE8cSzEkiQZOUvgO1WKpyQ2RodNMPTpJAL4zWbHYB35dsSkRVZ7RqHtDCY6zJFsul7M6NEPXnI5oMIGCpC+cCKMIULVkwwgGIAfWkPCYtQ+LIGI1xUtwkAMtOedh1HMdnOpGjNCwEB51jJc6mJEc-SoRgAwFcLItkqhLN8mTRUZFdgkSlK0pUKgkUGoIcrkPK8OSCbc0XeNyu9RqetEfT-OnZqIA6qK2sTLlvly0b5smiA6uW87BnkxislY9i7BaACsDURRPD8LlAOA9ApAYDr4MQ6LdtgqKGGG0iCogYaTvyhhiMh9BptkWaVFmZTA0Pfc5iooA)

Comment: Try to initialize it with `let ending_time: number = null;` so it's not undefined

Comment: shouldn't this be `for (let j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {` instead of `array[0]`

Comment: @Reza not necessarily, if all rows have the same number of elements

Comment: testingShift is defined? Then try `Object.assign(obj1, obj2);`

Comment: Instead of `if (j === 0) { continue }`, this can be avoided by starting the loop at `for (let j = 1; ...)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Common pattern when variable is used before being assigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53415708/common-pattern-when-variable-is-used-before-being-assigned)

Comment: It is a common issue - you either need to declare your variables with type annotation ` | undefined` (I actually prefer it this way, as it is safer) or use the definite assignment assertion (concise, but suffers from the same problem all assertions suffer - lack of safety net).

Comment: Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61598241/11407695) from jcalz

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will not know that the seemingly non-assignment will be handled by the code logic.

It is safe to assign the variables to anything to get the compiler to shut up.  The following was tested and the results where the same.

## Update

The testing was made consistent by replacing all the `Math.random()` calls with constants like `0.4`.

```
    let workid: number = 0;
    let starting_time: number = 0;
    let ending_time: number = 0;
```

Comment: I tried this, but then the output is wrong. If you will check the output array object then you can see all the workAreaId, startTime, endTime have same values 0, which should not be.

Comment: I believe that is because of the randomisation that you have.  I replaced the Math.random() with 0.2 and then with 0.5.  Under both circumstances the output was consistent with the initialisation and without.

I will update my answer to indicate this.